# Accessing the position of an array takes the whole thing instead of just the first element on inline intelx86 asm

Tags: arrays, c, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I was trying to access element by element of my array of chars (initialized with calloc) in order to then convert each element to its hexadecimal representation, but when the lenght of the string goes above 1, it kind of takes all of the elements instead of only the first one when doing `mov ecx,[eax]` which should only go for the first element

This is my code:

```
//Initialize array
char* myArray = (char*)calloc(8,sizeof(char));
printf("Type the array: ");
scanf("%s",myArray);
__asm {
    mov eax,myArray
    mov ecx,[eax]
    push ecx
    push format
    call printf
   }
```

When the array is **'A'** I get
**65** which is the ascii representation (that's what I expect)

But when the array is **'AB'** I get **16961** instead of 65

I don't quite understand why this is happening or if I missing something.

Pd. I Know I have to make a loop to iterate over all of the characters, but this is the part that is giving me problems, so I skipped the loop.

Comment: What is 'format'?

Comment: `mov ecx,[eax]`: Here `ecx` is a 32-bit register so this is a 32-bit load; you get 4 bytes starting at the desired address.  You want to load just one byte and  zero-extend into the full 32-bit register: `movzx ecx, byte ptr [eax]`.

Comment: Separate bug: you also forgot to clean up the stack after calling `printf`.